# configuration file in javascriptservices react-redux template

Tags: typescript, webpack, javascriptservices

I know this one is a very common question, and I have seen it being answered multiple times in multiple sites, but i could not manage to get it working The thing is I am consuming and api for a react component (I am using typescript 2.4.1 and webpack 2.5.1):

```
....
fetch("some/url/api/", method:"POST",...).then(/*some code*/)
```

I want to automatically detect in which environment the app is, and consume the right api depending if it's prod or dev.

Searching through web I could manage to put this together in webpack.config:

```
...
var API_URL = {
  production: JSON.stringify('http://some.server.example'),
  development:  JSON.stringify('http://localhost:xxxx')
}

var environment = process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production'?'production':'development'
```

...

```
const sharedConfig = () =>({
  ...
  plugins:[
    ...
    new webpack.DefinePlugin({
      'API_URL':API_URL[environment]  
    })
  ]
});
```

By calling fetch like this:
`fetch(API_URL+"api/endpoint"`).
i got error saying:

```
Cannot find name 'API_URL'.any
```

Should I import something specific to get API_URL value. I thought that API_URL would be globally accesible. Any help would be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This error is because typescript compiler is not aware that webpack will provide `API_URL`, so it's actually doing its job great, and warning you that you are using a non existent variable. You know that the build will supply this though, so you can let it know that it exists by declaring it
first

```
declare const API_URL: string
//...
fetch(API_URL + "api/endpoint").then(/* ... */)
```

Comment: Oh man, thanks a lot. it was the declare const what I was missing. I must say I am struggling with Typescript. I had to remove stringify to make it work , tough. Anyway I'll accept it as answer because it solved my problem

Comment: Ahhh sorry I completely missed that you had already stringifyed those URLs earlier on, will amend the answer to avoid confusion. Hang on in there it's worth the effort!